# Query to count the failure test cases and group by day, but missing the `0`s

Tags: sql

I was setting up some dashboards with Grafana, to count everyday Passes and Failures of the Function test. I tired the SQL code below but it never displays the 0 data( When there is no Failure in one day, the date will not appear in the query result set).

I believe this is a platform independent issue.

```sql
SELECT
  count(status) AS "Fail"
FROM function_test
WHERE status = false
GROUP BY date_time
```

Expected results:

```
-----------------------
day01       |   100
-----------------------
day02       |   200
-----------------------
day03       |   0
-----------------------
day04       |   10
-----------------------
```

Actual results:

```
-----------------------
day01       |   100
-----------------------
day02       |   200
-----------------------
day04       |   10
-----------------------
```

The SQL Executed smoothly, no error message.

Comment: What's your DBMS?

Comment: @BarbarosÖzhan Currently I'm not using any DBMS, Grafana provides a interface that you can manually compose the SQL query and visualize it in a chart. This issue happens in every database. and I'm sure this is a logical error rather than a syntax mistake. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps You can find the answer here
https://blog.csdn.net/ouyang111222/article/details/77638826

Build a result set for the last seven days, then do a left join with the result set of the query

```sql
select a.click_date,ifnull(b.count,0) as count
from (
    SELECT curdate() as click_date
    union all
    SELECT date_sub(curdate(), interval 1 day) as click_date
    union all
    SELECT date_sub(curdate(), interval 2 day) as click_date
    union all
    SELECT date_sub(curdate(), interval 3 day) as click_date
    union all
    SELECT date_sub(curdate(), interval 4 day) as click_date
    union all
    SELECT date_sub(curdate(), interval 5 day) as click_date
    union all
    SELECT date_sub(curdate(), interval 6 day) as click_date
) a left join (
  select date(create_time) as datetime, count(*) as count
  from arms_task
  group by date(create_time)
) b on a.click_date = b.datetime;
```

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps I sound the answer myself.

Just select all the rows (No `WHERE` just select all the rows at the very first) and perform a conditional count.

The code is as followed.

```sql
SELECT
  count(IF(status = false,true,null)) AS "Fail"
FROM function_test
GROUP BY date_time
```

Answer (score 1):

You can filter the 0 values with `IF` statements

```
IF(status = false,true,null)
```

With this query command, It is able for you to filter the empty rows